# 'PermissionGroup' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<PermissionGroup>' Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, permissions

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "Permissions",
      home: PermissionPage(),
    );
  }
}

class PermissionPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PermissionPageState createState() => _PermissionPageState();
}

class _PermissionPageState extends State<PermissionPage> {
  PermissionStatus _status;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    PermissionHandler()
        .checkPermissionStatus(PermissionGroup.locationWhenInUse)
        .then(_updatePermissionStatus);
  }

  void _requestPermission() {
    PermissionHandler()
        .requestPermissions(PermissionGroup.locationWhenInUse)
        .then(_onStatusRequested);
  }

  void _onStatusRequested(Map<PermissionGroup, PermissionStatus> statuses) {
    final status = statuses[PermissionGroup.locationWhenInUse];
    _updatePermissionStatus(status);
  }

  void _updatePermissionStatus(PermissionStatus status) {
    if (status != _status) {
      setState(() {
        _status = status;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Permissions"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text("Permission Status -> $_status"),
              SizedBox(
                height: 50.0,
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text("Request Location Permission"),
                onPressed: _requestPermission,
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

```
void _requestPermission() {
PermissionHandler()
    .requestPermissions(PermissionGroup.locationWhenInUse)
    .then(_onStatusRequested);
```

}

in this above method the below given error is shown

> The argument type 'PermissionGroup' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List'.

I'm a newbie to Flutter, just a week ago I started Flutter.
Please Friends help me to resolve this error.
or if there is any other more efficient way to ask user permissions then please tell me that also.